# Stop python command interpreter from echoing

Tags: python, echo, interpreter

In Linux, python3, I paste this code at the >>> python command-line...

```
my_string = "Blackpool rock is magic"

string_split = my_string.split()    # creates a list.
                                    # Elements of which are each
                                    # word in the string.

print(f"len of string = {len(my_string)}")

for t in range(len(string_split)):
    print(f"string_split[{t}] = {string_split[t]}")

print(f"string_split = {string_split}")
```

Inbetween the pasted code, I see some output inbetween some coded lines
e.g.
[image]

1. How can I get all my print statement to appear at the end of the code and not be interspersed with the code (even though I can see it being useful for debugging)? - Is there an "code echo off" like feature?
2. Am I right in thinking after a For loop you need to have a blank line?
3. When pasting code sometime I need to press enter a couple of time to complete the code. Is there an escape character or something to ensure the program terminates without needing to press enter 1 or two times?

Comment: Put all the code in a function and call the function

Comment: Hahaha. Yes, of course! Thank you!!! Works! :)
But I still have the problem with having to press enter a few times when pasting the function into the CLI and am still unsure as to why I sometimes get errors after a For loop unless I have a blank line.

Comment: @Micklos, this is a feature of the interactive environment. If you are typing in a function, or `if` statement and need indentation, the prompt changes to `...`. You need an extra blank line to signal to the interpreter that you want to dedent. If you find this super annoying, you might try using an editor (Geany, Thonny, PyCharm, VSCode etc) that will allow you to run a Python script right from the editor. In those editors, when the script runs a console window pops up to show any outputs from your script.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification bfris. It's probably my fault rather than the CLIs, but it was a bit annoying given I kept stumbling into it. But still, my journey into python is amazing, asisted by kind people like yourself willing to help and advise  :)